# Limit of $u_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2k}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, solution-verification

I want to find the limit of this sequence if it exists :

$$
u_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2k}}
$$

My attempt is to first remark that for $k\in\{1,...,n\}$ :

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2n}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2k}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}\implies\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+2n}}\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2k}}\leq\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}
$$
Which leads to :
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{n}}}\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2k}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{n^2}}}\implies\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}u_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2k}} = 1
$$

The last implication follows from the fact that the square root function is continuous at $x = 1$ and the squeeze theorem.

I would like to know first if my attempt is correct and if you have other ideas to show this that can be enlightening !

Thank you a lot

Comment: You forgot to type limit after $\implies$ but otherwise, your proof is fine.

Comment: Great, thank you for your comment !

Comment: Just for you rcuriosity : If $n$ is large (say $n=5$) $$u_n=1-\frac{1}{2 n}+\frac{1}{8 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$

Comment: I would use $${1\over n+1}\le {1\over \sqrt{n^2+2k}}\le {1\over n}$$